# How to link powerBI embedded capacity to powerBI workspace in terraform

Tags: azure, powerbi, terraform

I run the following terraform code

```
resource "azurerm_powerbi_embedded" "powerbi" {
  count               = var.environment != "dev" ? 0 : 1
  name                = "biarm${var.app_name}${var.environment}"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = "rg-arm-${var.app_name}-${var.environment}"
  sku_name            = "A1"
  mode                = "Gen2"
  administrators      = [module.pbi_object_id.env_shared_kv_secret_value, data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
  provider            = azurerm.saas-shared
}
provider "powerbi" {
  tenant_id     = data.azuread_client_config.current.tenant_id
  client_id     = module.pbi_client_id.env_shared_kv_secret_value
  client_secret = module.pbi_secret.env_shared_kv_secret_value
}

resource "powerbi_workspace" "myworkspace" {
  name        = "Workspace for ${var.environment}-${var.location}-${var.instance_number}"
  capacity_id = azurerm_powerbi_embedded.powerbi.id
}
```

This code fails with the following error

```
│ Error: Capacity id /subscriptions/xxxxxxx-9a95-4b71-8290-0f8b11f4d5f5/resourceGroups/rg-arm-shared-dev/providers/Microsoft.PowerBIDedicated/capacities/biarmshareddev not found or logged-in user doesn't have capacity admin rights
│
│   with powerbi_workspace.myworkspace,
│   on power-bi.tf line 61, in resource "powerbi_workspace" "myworkspace":
│   61: resource "powerbi_workspace" "myworkspace" {
│
```

azurerm_powerbi_embedded exposes only one attribute, which is id. This is not GUID but rather Azure resource id. powerbi_workspace expects capacity id, which seems to be a GUID. My question is if it's possible to make this connection in terraform at all or should I create those resources separately and then connect them in powerbi portal.

Answer (score 0):

I checked with the following code.

```
data "azuread_application" "name" {
  display_name = "powbiapp"
}

data "azuread_service_principal" "svp" {
  application_id = data.azuread_application.name.application_id
}


resource "azurerm_powerbi_embedded" "example" {
  name                = "powerbiapp"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku_name            = "A1"
  administrators      = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id  , data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id, data.azuread_service_principal.svp.object_id  ]
}

provider "powerbi" {
  tenant_id     = "7xxxx"
  client_id     = "8xxxxxxxxxx5"
  client_secret = "eYjxxxxxxxxxIcv-"
}

 resource "powerbi_workspace" "myworkspace" {
   name        = "Workspacefrpowbi"
   capacity_id = azurerm_powerbi_embedded.example.id
 }
```

[image]

Make sure the  user has administrator rights like **Office 365 Global Administrator** or ***Power BI Service Administrator.***

And check for Delegated and application permissions.

Check if all the permissions required to access PowerBi like capacity admin permissions are added and if not using service principal make sure the `Tenant.ReadWrite.All` permissions `Capacity.Read.All` permissions are **granted admin consent.**

[image]

[image]

Assign  the users to  have contributor permissions who assign a workspace to a capacity if they're an admin of that workspace.

Add power Bi admin role according to the requirement .

[image]

Comment: Hi @kavyaS you ommitted from your code the most important part, could you please add resource "powerbi_workspace" "myworkspace" where the capacity_id comes from.